# Calling a parent method from a child class

Tags: php, class, inheritance, methods, parent-child

I am having some difficulty with class inheritance. I have 5 classes all of which access my database with create, update and delete methods which I have made abstract so that I can push them into a MasterDatabase class and then have them all extend this class. The problem I am having is with the basic inheritance concept. I have looked through SOF and many people have asked similar questions but not quite this one.

```
  class DatabaseMaster {

    public function  create() {
        $attributes = $this->attributes();
        $question_marks = array();
        foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
        $question_marks[] = "?";
         }
        $place_holder = array_intersect_key($attributes, get_object_vars($this));
        $place_holder = array_values($place_holder);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".self::$table_name." (";
        $sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
        $sql .= ") VALUES (";
        $sql .= join(", ", array_values($question_marks));
        $sql .= ")";
        $query = $handler->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($place_holder);
   }

 }
```

Now if I have a class User. And I wish to this to extend DatabaseMaster, I presume it can't inherit this create function as it is above? My issue is with my reference to $this->attributes in the method for example. The DatabaseMaster has no attributes, but of course my User class does. If I run $user->create(); it doesn't work and I assume its because of this. How does one overcome this problem? I apologise for over using SOF at the moment!

This works....

```
 public function  create() {
    $attributes = $this->attributes();
    $question_marks = array();
    foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
    $question_marks[] = "?";
    }
    $place_holder = array_intersect_key($attributes, get_object_vars($this));
    $place_holder = array_values($place_holder);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (";
    $sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
    $sql .= ") VALUES (";
    $sql .= join(", ", array_values($question_marks));
    $sql .= ")";
    $query = $handler->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($place_holder);
}
```

So my question is clearly....how does one make the table name dynamic in the method so that it refers to the child when the child calls it?

Comment: The issue here is with the reference to SELF::$TABLE_NAME. Can you call 'self' in a parent method in this way and expect it to refer to the childs table name when the child calls the method?

Answer (score 0):

You **can** interpret the method "as-is". Consider the following example:

```
class P {

        function create() {
                echo $this->attributes . "\n";
        }
}

class C extends P {
        public $attributes = "hello!";
}

$c = new C;

$c->create();
```

This works just as you'd expect it, and the `create()` method on the parent echoes the value of `$attributes` as defined in the child.

Comment: You aren't wrong..I can see that your example works fine. I can't get my user to inherit this create function though....